# how to calculate the average key search for AES-128bit?

Tags: encryption, key-size

> Assume that an attacker has a special purpose application specific
>   integrated circuit (ASIC) which checks $5\times 10^{8}$ keys per second, and she has a budget of $\$1$ million.
>   One ASIC costs $\$50$, and we assume $100\%$ overhead for integrating the ASIC (manufacturing the printed circuit boards, power supply, cooling, etc.).
>
> How many ASICs can we run in parallel with the given budget?
>   How long does an average key search take? Relate this time to the age of the Universe, which is about $10^{10}$ years.

I know that we can run $20\ 000$ ASICs with ONE million budget, but I don't understand how to calculate the average key search, is it $2.5 \times 10^{19}$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an exercise in arithmetic only tangentially related to cryptography.

Comment: You missed the '100% overhead' so you have 10,000 ASICs. Although there is also ongoing cost for power and cooling, which your teacher seems to have left out.

Answer (score 1):

Since key search is "embarrasingly parallel", i.e., you can have different ASICs searching different parts of the key space, you have $$20{,}000\approx 2\times 10^{11}$$ processors and the keyspace is of size $2^{128}$.
There are $$3600\times 24\times 365.25\approx 2^{24.9}$$ seconds in a year so you can check $$2^{11} \times 2^{24.9} \times 2^{28.9}\approx 2^{64.8}$$ keys per year, the last factor being $2^{28.9}\approx5\times 10^8$. So this gives
$$ 2^{127} \times 2^{-64.8} =2^{62.2}\approx 10^{18.72} \approx 5.25 \times 10^{18}$$years if I haven't made a mistake somewhere.

Also I interpreted your

> can search 5.108 keys per second

as $5\times 10^8.$

**Edit:** Fixed computation. Thanks, @dave_thompson_085

Comment: The key search would take *on average* 2^127 guesses, not 2^128.

Comment: You actually have 10,000 chips (see my comment on Q) each doing 5e8 trials/sec -> 5e12/sec~2^42/sec -> 2^67/year thus average about 2^60 years for completion which is conveniently close to 10^18 years. PS: if your 2^11 was correct (not quite) the sum of 11+24.9+28.9 is 64.8. (Sorry I'm too lazy to texify.)